# Angular HttpClient.get headers

Tags: angular, get, header, httpclient

i have this simple code as a service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpotifyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getQuery(query: string) {
    const cabecera: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer BQDWZC2Y_iSV3rfmAhv-QxDpmhhJbbmgCnspy7HpIZPX5CbJ74D4Xl4aOyXLUL4smF2gZ_V3wiSXLxdLFPY'
    });
    const url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/' + query;
    return this.http.get(url, { cabecera });
  }
  getNewReleases() {
    return this.getQuery('browse/new-releases').pipe(map( data => data['albums'].items));
  }
}
```

but i'm getting this error and i dont understand why.

> Argument of type '{ cabecera: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:
>   string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'. Object
>   literal may only specify known properties, and 'cabecera' does not
>   exist in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string |
>   string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return this.http.get(url, { cabecera });` line is semantically incorrect, this means/resolves to the following :

```
return this.http.get(url, 
    { cabecera : new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer BQDWZC2Y_iSV3rfmAhv-QxDpmhhJbbmgCnspy7HpIZPX5CbJ74D4Xl4aOyXLUL4smF2gZ_V3wiSXLxdLFPY'
    }) 
});
```

Which is wrong since the options object passed to the HTTP Client doesn't expect a key called `cabecera` but instead a `headers` key.

So this can be solved simply by replacing the line with this : `return this.http.get(url, { headers: cabecera });`

Comment: Thank you very much I've started learning this like 2 days ago